In the List Filter the starts with operator ( a* ) filters the value with A without entering the values in filter input
In the List Filter after the selection of the starts with operator ( a* ) filters the value which starts with the character A without entering the values in filter input. It happen with all other operator in the filter. Is there any reason for that?
Sample - List
this.gridOptions = {
  autoResize: {
    container: '#demo-container',
    rightPadding: 10
  },
  enableExcelExport: true,
  enableExcelCopyBuffer: true,
  enableFiltering: true,
  skipCompoundOperatorFilterWithNullInput:true,
  // enableFilterTrimWhiteSpace: true,
  i18n: this.translate,
  showCustomFooter: true, // display some metrics in the bottom custom footer

  // use columnDef searchTerms OR use presets as shown below
  presets: {
    filters: [
      { columnId: 'duration', searchTerms: [10, 98] },
      // { columnId: 'complete', searchTerms: ['5'], operator: '>' },
      { columnId: 'usDateShort', operator: '<', searchTerms: ['4/20/25'] },
      // { columnId: 'effort-driven', searchTerms: [true] },
    ],
    sorters: [
      { columnId: 'duration', direction: 'DESC' },
      { columnId: 'complete', direction: 'ASC' }
    ],
  },
  externalResources: [new ExcelExportService()],
};

In the List Filter after the selection of the starts with operator ( a* ) filters the value based on the character entered in the filter input.

Stack Overflow should be questions related to coding but in your case you did not provide any code of what you tried so far. If you read the Compound Filter docs, you can find that you can use skipCompoundOperatorFilterWithNullInput in your column filter options

As per your answer I have checked the filter using skipcompoundoperatorWithNullInput key and updated the tried code, It works for very first time of the operator selection without any value provided in the filter input. But Once the filter value is cleared and change the operator to "a*" starts with operator without any value provided in the filter input filters, it filters the value which starts with the character A

that was a small bug and it will be fixed in the next release
